# Using Checkbox submit form in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can i update a method in controller if a checkbox is checked? see image below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RmbK.jpg

```
>[HttpPost] 
>public ActionResult Update(int id) 
>{
> //code update status in db
> }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this (Razor syntax):

```
//for a checkbox 
@Html.CheckBox("chkName",false, new {onclick="this.form.submit();"})

//if using strongly typed model property
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=> model.chkName, new {onclick="this.form.submit();"})
```

Comment: i had done, thank you for reply<br/>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Admin", new { id = item.ID }, FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.CheckBox("CkbStatus", item.Status ? true : false, new { onclick="this.form.submit();"})
}

Comment: Note the use of `Checkbox` or `CheckboxFor` over `Editor` or `EditorFor`. Simply adding html attributes for `onclick="this.form.submit();"` isn't enough.