# How to set an event to be triggered to the controller by a checkbox in your view ASP.net MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So my problem is that i want to hang an event to a checkbox in the view like this:

as you can see i ask for a notification in the changeFilter() method as soon as the checkbox changes. However when i create that method in the controller like this:

public EventHandler changeFilter()

```
    {
        ViewBag.test = "test";
        return null;(ignore the null please i know it's bad)
    }
```

it doesn't give me any results sadly nor does it ever reach that code. i want to reach that code so i can put filters on a list runtime that it refreshes and modifies the search result.

Does anybody have experience with this or anybody knows anything about it? i'd love some help

Thanks a lot in advance,
Marijn

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding MVC.  This isn't WebForms, there aren't post-back events like this.  If all that needs to happen is some change to the client-side view in response to the event, handle it in JavaScript.  If there needs to also be some background server-side logic, use AJAX to call a controller action (ideally returning a JSON result).

Comment: well point is that i've already returned the result of the list so i can modify it with AJAX/JavaScript i geuss but then i'd be modifying only in the view which seems rather stupid to me either way an example of that would help as well

Comment: Why would it be "stupid" to put client-side logic in the view?  That's... exactly what the view is for.  It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish here, all the code you've shown does is set a string value, which isn't really something that needs to happen server-side.

Comment: Typically you'd use a form to POST the value to your controller method - [see here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721288/using-checkbox-submit-form-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: no true but that was just to check how to fire the event.... so is there any way to fire an event when the checkbox is changed to the controller or not?

Comment: wouldn't the form refresh the entire page?

Comment: Yes, but you haven't specified that you wanted it to do otherwise! What _do_ you actually want it to do?

Comment: i want to reach that code so i can put filters on a list runtime that it refreshes and modifies the search result. it's literally in the text.... basically the items that are currently in the model have to be modified so they match the filter i want to apply.. for example a list of people and then modify the search results on location with a checkbox runtime

Comment: ok, so if I understand correctly - you have a list of results on a page, you want a checkbox which filters the results again, but without refreshing the page?

Comment: yup that's the full explanation

Comment: It sounds like you've already filtered the data server-side, and now want to filter it again client-side, which seems odd. However if this is correct then then @Ashwath's answer is the way to go.  Google 'mvc ajax post' and you'll find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are coming from the ASP.Net Webforms, it will not work as you are requesting. you need to change little bit when you are using the MVC.  Here are the steps you need to follow,

- Please attach javascript method on click of your check box.
- in javascript method, make a ajax call to your controller method.
- In Ajax success handler, parse the json which is returned from the controller method.

Good luck...