# Checkbox updates index mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

Good afternoon everyone, I have an Index in my view that displays a table of restaurants (local in spanish). I added a checkbox to the view, I need the checkbox to filter the index while checked, if not then to show the complete index. I don't know if there is a way to do this with mvc,

**this is my view**

```
   @model IEnumerable<AutoPlanMCV.Models.Local>

<div class="row">
    <table class="col-md-12">
        <tr>
            <th>Nuevo</th>
            <th>Instaldo</th>
            <th>Capacitar</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.Count(x => x.Estado.State == "Nuevo")</td>
            <td>@Model.Count(x=> x.Estado.State =="Instalado")</td>
            <td>@Model.Count(x=>x.Estado.State == "Capacitar")</td>
        </tr>
            </table>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <label for="verBajas">Ver Bajas</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="verBajas" value="true" id="verBajas"/>

</div>

<div>   
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Crear nuevo Local", "Create")
        <br />

        @Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel", "ExportToExcel")
    </p>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary list-panel" id="list-panel">
            <div class="panel-heading list-panel-heading">
                <h1 class="panel-title list-panel-title">POS PDS UY</h1>


            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table id="assets-data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>V.Id</th>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Comercio</th>
                            <th>Direccion</th>
                            <th>Telefono</th>
                            <th>Ingreso</th>
                            <th>Provincia</th>
                            <th>Estado</th>
                            <th>Bonificado</th>
                            <th>Premium</th>
                            <th>Gestionar</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var asset in Model)
                        {

                            <tr>
                                <td>@asset.ViejoId</td>
                                <td>@asset.NuevoId</td>
                                <td>@asset.NombreComercio</td>
                                <td>@asset.Direccion</td>
                                <td>@asset.Telefono</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => asset.FechaInstalacion)</td>
                                <td>@asset.Provincia</td>
                                <td>@asset.Estado.State</td>
                                @if (asset.Bonificado == true)
                                {
                                    string i = "Bonificado";
                                    <td>@i</td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    string i = "No";
                                    <td>@i</td>
                                }

                                @if (asset.Premium == true)
                                {
                                    string i = "Premium";
                                    <td>@i</td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    string i = "No";
                                    <td>@i</td>
                                }

                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = asset.Id ,estadoid = asset.Estado.Id,proveedorid = asset.Proveedor.Id}) |
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = asset.Id }) |
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = asset.Id })|
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Comment", "AgregarComentario", new { id = asset.Id })
                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $('#assets-data-table').DataTable();
     });
    </script>

}
```

**this is the actionResult in my controller**

```
public ActionResult IndexAsset(bool verBajas = false)
    {


       var locales = db.Locales.Include(l => l.Estado).Include(l => l.Proveedor).Where(l => l.Proveedor.Nombre == "PDSUY");

        if(verBajas)
        {
            locales = db.Locales.Include(l => l.Estado).Include(l => l.Proveedor).Where(l => l.Proveedor.Nombre == "PDSUY").Where(l => l.Estado.State != "Bajas");
        } else if (verBajas == false)
        {
            locales = db.Locales.Include(l => l.Estado).Include(l => l.Proveedor).Where(l => l.Proveedor.Nombre == "PDSUY");
        }



        return View(locales.ToList());
    }
```

If I dont initialize "verBajas" as false, I get a null error, even though I set the value in the view as true.

Any Ideas are appreciated.

Comment: you are setting the value in the view but how are you submitting to the controller because i dont see any form

Comment: You can have a partial view of your list, then put an event on checkbox to see if it is checked or not, based on that get the list via ajax and display it on your View. 

The second option is you can put all of the checkboxes in a form and submit it back and show the view again.

Comment: @Emil can you please let me know, through this comment area(my inbox), if you want me to help you do this with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Please following these steps to solve your issue.  When you run the program, and click on the checkbox, your grid will change from 2 items to 1 item, as you want.

Create this table and data:

```
--instead of farout, use your database name
USE [farout]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Estado]    Script Date: 4/28/2017 4:26:47 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Estado](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [State] [varchar](10) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Estado] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Locale]    Script Date: 4/28/2017 4:26:48 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Locale](
    [ViejoId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NuevoId] [int] NULL,
    [NombreComercio] [int] NULL,
    [Direccion] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Telefono] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [FechaInstalacion] [int] NULL,
    [Provincia] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Estado] [int] NULL,
    [Bonificado] [bit] NULL,
    [Premium] [bit] NULL,
    [Proveedor] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Locale] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ViejoId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Proveedor]    Script Date: 4/28/2017 4:26:48 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Proveedor](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Estado] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Proveedor] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Estado] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Estado] ([Id], [State]) VALUES (1, N'Bajas')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Estado] ([Id], [State]) VALUES (2, N'Not Bajas')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Estado] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Locale] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Locale] ([ViejoId], [NuevoId], [NombreComercio], [Direccion], [Telefono], [FechaInstalacion], [Provincia], [Estado], [Bonificado], [Premium], [Proveedor]) VALUES (2, 1, 1, N'direction', N'4446666666', 1, N'provincia', 1, 1, 1, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Locale] ([ViejoId], [NuevoId], [NombreComercio], [Direccion], [Telefono], [FechaInstalacion], [Provincia], [Estado], [Bonificado], [Premium], [Proveedor]) VALUES (3, 1, 1, N'two', N'222222', 1, N'two', 2, 1, 1, 1)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Locale] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Proveedor] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Proveedor] ([Id], [Nombre], [Estado]) VALUES (1, N'PDSUY', 1)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Proveedor] OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Locale]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Locale_Estado] FOREIGN KEY([Estado])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Estado] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Locale] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Locale_Estado]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Locale]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Locale_Proveedor] FOREIGN KEY([Proveedor])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Proveedor] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Locale] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Locale_Proveedor]
GO
```

Right click on your models folder and add ADO.NET ENTITY DATA MODEL.  Call it Spanish and click okay.  EF Designer from Database is highlighted so click next.  Click new connection.  Type the server name, I use .\sqlexpress.  If you do not use windows authentication, put in your credentials.  Select your database name in the dropdown.  Click okay.  If you use windows authentication, wait till wizard prompts you and click 'yes include sensitive information..'.  Copy to your clipboard the item under 'save connection in settings..'.  Click next.  Under tables dbo, select the three tables:  Estado, Locale, and Proveedor.  Click finish.  Click okay twice when prompted.  Close your edmx diagram.

In your controller add this code:

```
public class Local
{
    public Locale LocalAttr { get; set; }
    public IList<DateTime> FechaInstalacion { get; set; }
    public bool theCheckbox { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexAsset(string chkName)
    {
        IList<Local> listOfViewModels = FactoredOut(bool.Parse(chkName));
        return View(listOfViewModels);
    }

    public ActionResult IndexAsset(bool verBajas = false)
    {
        IList<Local> listOfViewModels = FactoredOut(verBajas);
        return View(listOfViewModels);
    }

    IList<Local> FactoredOut(bool verBajas)
    {
        //instead of faroutEntities9, use the copy and paste item your copied in previous step
        using (faroutEntities9 db = new faroutEntities9())
        {
            var locales = db.Locales.Include(l => l.Estado1).Include(l => l.Proveedor1).
            Where(l => l.Proveedor1.Nombre == "PDSUY");

            if (verBajas)
            {
                locales = db.Locales.Include(l => l.Estado1).Include(l => l.Proveedor1).
                    Where(l => l.Proveedor1.Nombre == "PDSUY").Where(l => l.Estado1.State != "Bajas");
            }
            else if (verBajas == false)
            {
                locales = db.Locales.Include(l => l.Estado1).Include(l => l.Proveedor1).
                    Where(l => l.Proveedor1.Nombre == "PDSUY");
            }

            IList<Local> listOfViewModels = new List<Local>();

            var list = locales.ToList();
            Local localView = new Local { LocalAttr = list[0] };
            localView.FechaInstalacion = new List<DateTime>();
            localView.FechaInstalacion.Add(DateTime.Now);
            localView.FechaInstalacion.Add(DateTime.Parse("12/12/12"));
            listOfViewModels.Add(localView);

            if (list.Count > 1)
            {
                var list2 = locales.ToList();
                Local localView2 = new Local { LocalAttr = list[1] };
                localView2.FechaInstalacion = new List<DateTime>();
                localView2.FechaInstalacion.Add(DateTime.Now);
                localView2.FechaInstalacion.Add(DateTime.Parse("12/12/12"));
                listOfViewModels.Add(localView2);
            }
            return listOfViewModels;
        }
    }
```

In your view (use a full view without a partial page) add this code:

```
@model IEnumerable<except.Controllers.Local>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>IndexAsset</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    @*<link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>*@
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#assets-data-table').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <table class="col-md-12">
            <tr>
                <th>Nuevo</th>
                <th>Instaldo</th>
                <th>Capacitar</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Model.Count(x => x.LocalAttr.Estado1.State == "Nuevo")</td>
                <td>@Model.Count(x => x.LocalAttr.Estado1.State == "Instalado")</td>
                <td>@Model.Count(x => x.LocalAttr.Estado1.State == "Capacitar")</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
            <label for="verBajas">Ver Bajas</label>
            @*<input type="checkbox" name="verBajas" value="true" id="verBajas" />*@
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721288/using-checkbox-submit-form-in-asp-net-mvc
            @Html.CheckBox("chkName", false, new { onclick = "this.form.submit();" })
        }
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Crear nuevo Local", "Create")
            <br />
            @Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel", "ExportToExcel")
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary list-panel" id="list-panel">
                <div class="panel-heading list-panel-heading">
                    <h1 class="panel-title list-panel-title">POS PDS UY</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table id="assets-data-table" class="display table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>V.Id</th>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Comercio</th>
                                <th>Direccion</th>
                                <th>Telefono</th>
                                <th>Ingreso</th>
                                <th>Provincia</th>
                                <th>Estado</th>
                                <th>Bonificado</th>
                                <th>Premium</th>
                                <th>Gestionar</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var asset in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@asset.LocalAttr.ViejoId</td>
                                    <td>@asset.LocalAttr.NuevoId</td>
                                    <td>@asset.LocalAttr.NombreComercio</td>
                                    <td>@asset.LocalAttr.Direccion</td>
                                    <td>@asset.LocalAttr.Telefono</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => asset.FechaInstalacion)</td>
                                    <td>@asset.LocalAttr.Provincia</td>
                                    <td>@asset.LocalAttr.Estado1.State</td>
                                    @if (asset.LocalAttr.Bonificado == true)
                                    {
                                        string i = "Bonificado";
                                        <td>@i</td>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        string i = "No";
                                        <td>@i</td>
                                    }

                                    @if (asset.LocalAttr.Premium == true)
                                    {
                                        string i = "Premium";
                                        <td>@i</td>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        string i = "No";
                                        <td>@i</td>
                                    }
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit",
                                                new
                                                {
                                                    id = asset.LocalAttr.ViejoId,
                                                    estadoid = asset.LocalAttr.Estado1.Id,
                                                    proveedorid = asset.LocalAttr.Proveedor1.Id
                                                }) |
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = asset.LocalAttr.ViejoId }) |
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = asset.LocalAttr.ViejoId })|
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Comment", "AgregarComentario",
                                                new { id = asset.LocalAttr.ViejoId })
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```