# Asp.net MVC Checkbox Event HTTPPOST ServerSide

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

net mvc5 form and Using checkbox.

My condition is i need to Call HTTPPOST action immedaitely after selecting the checkbox(true)

Its something like HTTPPOST action should be called immediately after selecting the checkbox.

I need to pass Model as well to the HTTP Post.

can you please let me know whats the desired way to get this done ?

Comment: Using razor you can use `@Html.CheckBox("chkName",false, new {onclick="this.form.submit();"})` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721288/using-checkbox-submit-form-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using jquery to achieve this. Assuming your checkbox is nested in a form, you can use:

```
$(function () {
    $('#CheckBoxName').change(function () {
        $(this).closest("form")[0].submit();
    });
});
```

This will trigger a postback, calling the appropriate HttpPost method and sending the model as a parameter.

Comment: it helped to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript to react on a change of the checkbox then posting via ajax.

Here is an exemple :

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
    if (this.checked){
                var jsonModel = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';

                $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '@Url.Action("UrlOfPostAction")',
                data: { Model: jsonModel},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (res) {
                    //Do something
                }
                //manage errors
            });
    }
});
```